Docker Container running MySQL image keeps exiting just after a couple of seconds from starting
I'm working on a project and I have a MySQL DB that's supposed to be running in a docker container but whenever I build and start the container it runs for a second or two and then Exits with code 1.
The logs of the container shows nothing in regards of the previous behavior mentioned.
Here is the Dockerfile I wrote for the container.
FROM mysql:8.0

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=webtranslate 
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD} 
                            #^ This is supposed to be an ENV Variable

COPY my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf

RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/mysql
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/mysql

RUN touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
RUN touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
RUN touch /var/log/mysql/error.log

RUN chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
RUN  chown -R mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql
RUN chmod -R 755 /var/log/mysql


EXPOSE 3306

VOLUME /var/lib/mysql

cmd ["mysqld", "--console"]


and here is the logs from the container.
2024-04-25 16:14:05 2024-04-25 14:14:05+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.36-1.el8 started.
2024-04-25 16:14:05 2024-04-25 14:14:05+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2024-04-25 16:14:05 2024-04-25 14:14:05+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.36-1.el8 started.
2024-04-25 16:14:06 '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

I already tried running in console mode and just fiddling around trying some solutions I found online.

I'm wondering whether you need this custom image at all, or whether you can just docker run -e MYSQL_DATABASE=... -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=... mysql:8.0.

@HansKilian The Dockerfile as shown should use the base image's ENTRYPOINT.  Setting ENTRYPOINT resets the base image's CMD, but not vice versa.
